# Which Azure region is closest to me?

Tags: azure

I always wondered which Azure region is closest to me in terms of lowest latency.

I also have often needed to know what is the actual location or city of an Azure region. For example, where exactly is "West Europe" or "Central US"?

To answer these questions, once and for all, I made the site found in the answer below.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/geographies/#geographies

Comment: +1 for that link in your answer. Good information on latencies. For security reasons AWS, Azure, Google do not publish the actual physical location. I am surprised that this information has not been leaked. However, I want these data centers safe. If you do find out, please do not publish details. An approximate location by city is sufficient. Besides, I design based upon latency for the customer. That generally involves the POP locations. Once on the backbone, traffic is faster than the public Internet.

Comment: @JohnHanley very good point about latency for the customer and maybe if you have multiple clouds, you would need to know the latency from your other clouds and not from your workstation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to find the Azure region closest to you, you can use this free tool:

https://gyxi.com/which-azure-region-is-closest-to-me/

For your convenience, here is the list of Azure regions with their actual (closest) major city.

```
+-------------+----------------------+---------------+
|   Region    |       Azure ▾        |     Area      |
+-------------+----------------------+---------------+
| Sao Paolo   | Brazil South         | South America |
| Quebec      | Canada East          | North America |
| Pune        | Central India        | Asia          |
| Iowa        | Central US           | North America |
| Hong Kong   | East Asia            | Asia          |
| Virginia    | East US              | North America |
| Ireland     | Europe North         | Europe        |
| Netherlands | Europe West          | Europe        |
| Paris       | France Central       | Europe        |
| Germany     | Germany West Central | Europe        |
| Tokyo       | Japan East           | Asia          |
| Osaka       | Japan West           | Asia          |
| Seoul       | Korea Central        | Asia          |
| Illinois    | North Central US     | North America |
| Texas       | South Central US     | North America |
| Singapore   | Southeast Asia       | Asia          |
| Zurich      | Switzerland North    | Europe        |
| Dubai       | UAE North            | Asia          |
| London      | UK South             | Europe        |
| Cardiff     | UK West              | Europe        |
| Mumbai      | West India           | Asia          |
| California  | West US              | North America |
| Washington  | West US 2            | North America |
+-------------+----------------------+---------------+
```

Only public regions that support Linux Consumption Plan are included in this table because those are the requirements of the latency tool.

Answer (score 1):

The best way today would be to use the latency and download/upload speed test
https://www.azurespeed.com/Azure/Latency

Answer (score 1):

This one is pretty good one showing range of regions average response time depending on your current location: [Azure Speed Test 2.0](https://azurespeedtest.azurewebsites.net/)